# Можно ли открыть авторизацию vk sdk в диалоговом окне?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Что бы открыть обычное активити в виде диалога я использую стиль

```
<style name="myDialogNoTitleBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

и просто добавляю в манифесте к нужному активити

```
android:theme="@style/myDialogNoTitleBar"
```

но для авторизации через vk sdk используется функция

```
VKSdk.login(this, scope);
```

которая сама открывает нужное активити и делает всё что надо.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Вы хотите запустить активити с логином из диалога? Типа открыли диалог, нажали кнопку и открылась активити с логином? И вы не знаете что вместо `this` передать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ни в коем случае. Я хочу открыть окно с формой логина в диалоге, а не новым активити.

Answer (score 1):

В манифесте при подключении VKSDK надо прописать активити, где, в частности, указывается стиль

В исходниках он выглядит так:

```
<style name="VK.Transparent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

---

Соответственно, вы можете попробовать определить свой стиль с такими же атрибутами, но унаследовать его от диалогового стиля и назначить этой вконтактовой активити в манифесте

В стилях:

```
<style name="MY.VK.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

В манифесте:

```
<activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity" android:label="ServiceActivity" android:theme="@style/MY.VK.Transparent" />
```

Comment: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity@theme value=(@style/MY.VK.Transparent) from AndroidManifest.xml:44:13-53
 is also present at [com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.7] AndroidManifest.xml:15:13-50 value=(@style/VK.Transparent).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at [file] to override.`

После этого я добавил `tools:replace="android:theme"` и получил `Error:The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound.`

Comment: @user3239600, попробуйте или перенести "tools:replace" в тег `application` или сменить родительскую тему `MY.VK.Transparent` на тему не из библиотеки поддерки